# Why aren't the 3 columns filling the parent div? (using display: table)

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the footer */
.footer {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>CSS Template using Float</h2>
<p>In this example, we have created a header, three equal columns and a footer. On smaller screens, the columns will stack on top of each other.</p>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">Column1</div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">Column2</div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">Column3</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

it only fills the div if you change line 33 to `.row:after {` but i don't understand why

ignore this: dafasdfsadifafijaspfisjdpfiudsafuahfuahifu ufhaduf haufdhaosdiufh auhfodiusfhaouf fuafdiuaf 
fsjfosaijf afa ifpasdiofjas fuifh a ufdhaoiufha s uf hafoiudashf iu uadsifhaoiuf has auh foau
hf h fghhfh fsaf sf sf f
f
asdf
safsafisajfosaijf iojfsodfijosaifj ifjasofijsaofasof jaoiajof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are floating the `column` div, you need to clear the float. What `row:after` does is clears the float using pseudo element.

For simplicity sake you can also use

```css
.row {
  clear: both
}
```

More on floats here: [The How and Why of Clearing Floats](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)